# Docker-compose is dependent on the locally installed packages outside the Docker environment

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to create build my image in my local environment but I have been having a few issues.

It looks like when doing `docker-compose up`, Docker compose does not run unless I have installed all the packages locally in my project outside of Docker.

Here is the Scenario.

I have a simple `index.js` file with one package (`express`)

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/health', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('ok'));
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('magic happens here'));
```

A Dockerfile to build the image

```
FROM node:6.9.5

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/applications/test_dc

RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json /src
COPY . /src

RUN npm install
VOLUME ["/src", "/var/log/applications/test_dc"]
EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` file to start the project up (I have removed the linked images to keep it minimal)

```
version: "2.1"
services:
    api:
        build: .
        container_name: test_dc
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - .:/src
```

The idea that is anyone can clone the repository and run the docker compose command to:

- Build the image from the Dockerfile (Install deps and start up)
- Spin up the containers.
- Hit the health route.

This means I do not need to run `npm install` in the local project outside of docker.

This is however failing on `docker-compose up`

[image]

This however is solved when I run `npm install` locally.

Isn't this against the whole idea of Docker? That a project should be isolated from the rest of the system?

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

### External volume mounts can mask image contents

You appear to be wanting your project code to live in `/src`, as seen in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src

COPY package.json /src
COPY . /src
```

But in docker-compose.yml, you are mounting an external path as `/src`.

```
volumes:
  - .:/src
```

The external mount will take precedence, and obscure everything that was built into your image in the Dockerfile (as well as the volume that you defined in Dockerfile).

### Running startup tasks using a custom entrypoint

The usual way to handle this is by using an entrypoint script that runs your installer at container startup.

entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
npm install
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

At container startup, the entrypoint script is run, with the external volume already mounted. Thus, `npm install` can run and install modules there. When that is done, the `CMD` is executed. In your case, that is `npm start`.

### Why you would want to use a custom entrypoint

One reason to use a container is to create isolation. That is, you want the image to be isolated and not rely on your external environment. So why would you want to use an external mount at all?

The answer is that during development you often want to avoid frequent rebuilds. Since images are immutable, every single change would require a rebuild and restart of the container. So every code change... yeah, it would be pretty slow.

A good compromise is to build your images to be fully contained, but during development you externally mount the code so you can make changes very quickly without a rebuild step. Once you are ready to release code, you can remove the external mount and do one final build. Since you're copying the files you were mounting into the container, it's all the same. And the `npm install` step in the build is the same one you run in the custom `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Okay I need to read a little bit more on Docker volumes but this seems to make sense.

The objective of me using volumes is to ensure that:

 - The local environment is isolated from the local system (i.e I can
   just clone the repo and run `docker-compose up`)
 - Any changes I make in the application updates the image/container.

How can I rewrite/discard the current volumes configuration in the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to avoid the custom script?

Comment: @JohnKariuki The usual use case for this setup is for faster development (without constantly doing rebuild of your images). I updated my answer with some more about that.

Comment: Cool. Checking it out now.